# Connecting HTML and JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to connect my JQuery file (Or .js file) to my HTML file.  The problem is that when I mouse over my Div with the ID of zom nothing happens.  Am I connecting this wrong?  My JQuery looks like this:

```
$(Homepage.html).ready(function() {
    $('#zom').mouseenter(function() {
        $('#zom').fadeTo('fast', 0.25)
    });
    $('#zom').mouseleave(function() {
        $('#zom').fadeTo('fast', 1)
    });
});
```

And my HTML:

```
<div id="zom">Zombie Nom</div>
```

I do have the two files in the same file directory and I do have my html, body, and other tags but I just showed you my div.  Thank you and by the way I am 11 so if this seems really simple don't downvote me.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle of your code? http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1):

You have `$(Homepage.html).ready(function() {`, but you haven't defined a JS variable called `Homepage`.

You probably want: `$(document).ready(function() {`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#zom').mouseenter(function() {
        $('#zom').fadeTo('fast', 0.25);
    });
    $('#zom').mouseleave(function() {
        $('#zom').fadeTo('fast', 1);
    });
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aMjjN/)

Answer (score -3):

Try to put it in one file something like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
//include jquery, so the code can work
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#zom').mouseenter(function() {
        $('#zom').fadeTo('fast', 0.25)
    });
    $('#zom').mouseleave(function() {
        $('#zom').fadeTo('fast', 1)
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="zom">Zombie Nom</div>
</body>
</html>
```

If you are unsecure in using jQuery take a look at: [www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp) 
Its a very easy understandable tutorial with very detailed examples. Perfect for getting involved.

Greetings

Comment: there is no such thing as a `Homepage.html` object/html element

Comment: That is the file name for my HTML page with the div